# How to add wallpaper with CSS on a Hugo theme?

Tags: css, sass

For the main discussion, see here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-do-i-add-a-wallpaper-to-my-site-page-cannot-figure-it-out/49084/1

I was told to ask here. Am using the [JuiceBar](https://github.com/hotjuicew/hugo-JuiceBar) theme on my Hugo-made site. The theme I'm using makes this tricky. My _background.scss code is:

```
@import "_variables";


    .background-container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        var($tertiary3hover) 100%,
        var($tertiary2) 100%
      );
      clip-path: ellipse(148% 70% at 91% -14%);
    }
```

My baseof.html code is:

```
    <body class="background-container">
        {{- partial "header.html" . -}}
        <main>
        {{- block "main" . }}{{- end }}
        </main>
        {{- partial "footer.html" . -}}

    </body>
```

My _variables.scss imports for bodyof.html are:

```
$tertiary2: #313131;
$tertiary3hover: #099dd7;
```

And then I've added

```
@import "background";
```

to my styles.scss file.

This all semi-works. For example, this is how it's coming out currently:
https://i.imgur.com/RYAr56x.png

I want the blue/grey, but my results are grey/white, even though my variables and whatnot are for the blue and grey. I have with also tried messing with the “0%” and “100%” parts too.

**But here is the entire big issues with this**:
With the

```
<body class="background-container">
```

added to my baseof.html file, it wipes out the bottom half of my entire site/page. This is how it looks WITHOUT that code added (normal): https://i.imgur.com/IeHhiss.png

When the code is then added, it wipes out the entire blog post section. How can I achieve the blue/grey background design I want without destroying the site?

I have tried just about everything at this point. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This would best be accomplished in the following manner:

- Set the `background-color` of the body to what you want the bottom half to be.
- Set the `background-color` of the element and give it the `clip-path`.

This will ensure you always have the nice separation.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #313131;
}
.bg {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: #099dd7;
  clip-path: ellipse(148% 70% at 91% -14%);
}
```

```html
<body><div class="bg"></div></body>
```

The reason that the `linear-gradient` doesn't work is that the `clip-path` that is being applied hides the bottom half of it.

Comment: Hi, @Dan-Mullin! So, I put the CSS in my _background.scss file and the <body> HTML stuff in my baseof.html file. Your CSS is getting the colors correct for the background, but depending where I place the HTML, it still wipes out some of the site. Here is baseof.html file: https://i.imgur.com/HWFU0Y5.png - If I put it under the body tag and </div> before </body> I get: https://i.imgur.com/c49xpqM.png - If placing code and </div> right under <body> I get: https://i.imgur.com/Mowkwmo.png - As you can see, it seems to do everything except what I need it, haha. Please help.